# Several error after transfer APEX Application between hosts with same apex version

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I transferred a application from a host with apex 20.1 and Database 19.3 to another host with apex 20.1 and Database Xe 11g.

My application only use a schema that I transferred it completely with Data Pump.

1- After this transfer for each page that have intReport i see javaScript Error!

2- One of my page doesn't work, completely and show a error ( [can see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0il4i.png) ). I Finded problem of this page that have a master detail structure!
I have a LIST ITEM in in detail intGrid. When i change it to TEXT ITEM page work correctly!!

Do you have similar problem after transfer application between hosts with same apex version?
Do you have any idea about this errors?

Comment: Do the two databases use the same database character set?  My wild guess on the buffer too small error is that you've got variables defined in terms of byte length semantics and the two databases have different character sets so the same string takes a different number of bytes in the two environments.

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle Database XE 11g](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-prior-releases.html) is actually running database version 11.2.0.2.0. If you look at the section [Oracle Database Requirements for APEX 20.1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmig/Oracle-AE-installation-requirements.html#GUID-ED8FE111-A861-4A54-938B-CB3664D49C68) you will see in the release notes:

> Oracle Application Express release 20.1 requires an Oracle Database release 11.2.0.4 or later...

If you are looking to transfer your application to an XE environment, I would recommend using the [latest version of the XE database](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html) which is version 18.4.0.0.0